# Extremely accurate fractions for square roots

Tags: approximation, radicals, upper-lower-bounds

### Approximation

The following is a simple and amazingly accurate way to get a rational approximation to square roots:

- To find $\sqrt n$, guess a fraction $p/q$ near $\sqrt n$. (So $nq^2 \approx p^2$).
- Let $a = nq^2 + p^2$.
- Let $b = nq^2 - p^2$.
- $\displaystyle \sqrt n \approx \frac{a - b^2/(2a)}{2pq}$

For accuracy we want $|b|$ to be small, and can usually get it to be 1, without much effort.

### Explanation

Start with $s_0=p/q$ and use the [Babylonian Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) to get a first estimate
$$s_1 = \frac{s_0 + n/s_0}{2} = \frac{p^2 + nq^2}{2pq} = \frac{a}{2pq}$$
This excess will always be an overestimate by approximately
$$\frac{(s_0 - n/s_0)^2}{2s_1} = \frac{(p^2 - nq^2)^2}{4pqa} = \frac{b^2}{4apq}$$
Subtracting this excess gives the approximation formula.

### Problem

I want to get an estimate of (or a bound for) the error of approximation. My guess is it is something like $|p/q-\sqrt n|^4$.

### Examples

For $\sqrt 2$ try $p/q=3/2$, $a=7$, $b=1$,  $\sqrt 2 \approx \frac{17 - 1/34}{12}$

$\qquad\color{red}{1.41421}356237310 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{1.41421}568627451 \quad\text{approximation}$

If instead we start with a better estimate $p/q=7/5$ we get $a=99$, $b=1$ and $\sqrt 2 \approx \frac{99 - 1/198}{70}$, giving a much better accuracy:

$\qquad\color{red}{1.41421356}237310 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{1.41421356}421356 \quad\text{approximation}$

For $\sqrt 3$ try $p/q=7/4$, $a=97$, $b=1$,  $\sqrt 3 \approx \frac{97 - 1/194}{56}$

$\qquad\color{red}{1.7320508}0756888 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{1.7320508}1001472 \quad\text{approximation}$

For $\sqrt 5$ try $p/q=9/4$, $a=161$, $b=1$,  $\sqrt 5 \approx \frac{161 - 1/322}{72}$

$\qquad\color{red}{2.236067977}49979 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{2.236067977}91580 \quad\text{approximation}$

For $\sqrt 7$ try $p/q=8/3$, ...

$\qquad\color{red}{2.64575131}106459 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{2.64575131}233596 \quad\text{approximation}$

For $\sqrt 11$ try $p/q=10/3$, ...

$\qquad\color{red}{3.316624790}35540 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{3.316624790}61977 \quad\text{approximation}$

For $\sqrt 13$ try $p/q=18/5$, ...

$\qquad\color{red}{3.60555127546}399 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{3.60555127546}653  \quad\text{approximation}$

For $\sqrt 15$ try $p/q=31/8$, ...

$\qquad\color{red}{3.8729833462074}2 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{3.8729833462074}5 \quad\text{approximation}$

As an example where $b \ne 1$, for this last example, if we tried $p/q = 27/7$, we would get $a=1464$, $b=6$ giving the answer $\frac{1464 - 36/2928}{378}$ which  3.872983346 3440

$\qquad\color{red}{3.872983346}20742 \quad\text{exact}\\
 \qquad\color{red}{3.872983346}34400 \quad\text{approximation}$

Comment: Let $f(x) = \frac12(x + \frac{n}{x})$ and $s_k = \begin{cases} \frac{p}{q}, & k = 0,\\ f(s_{k-1}) & k > 0\end{cases}$, then your approximation is $s_2$. For general $k > 0$, one has
$\frac{s_k - \sqrt{n}}{s_k + \sqrt{n}} = \left(\frac{s_0 - \sqrt{n}}{s_0 + \sqrt{n}}\right)^{2^k}$

Comment: @achillehui, you should post that as an answer!

Comment: @achillehui, thanks. I didn't notice that this was just $s_2$. That is a complete answer. If you post it, I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a rational number, use Newton method to generate a more and more accurate rational number.

For example, for $\sqrt{15}$, using as you did $x_0=\frac {31}8$, you will generate numbers $x_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & a_n  & b_n & \text{decimal} \\
 0 & 31 & 8 & 3.8750000000000000000 \\
 1 & 1921 & 496 & 3.8729838709677419355 \\
 2 & 7380481 & 1905632 & 3.8729833462074524357 \\
 3 & 108942999582721 & 28128961537984 & 3.8729833462074168852
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you start with $x_0=\frac p q$ for $x^2=a$ ($a$ being an integer or a rational number), you have
$$x_1=\frac{a q}{2 p}+\frac{p}{2 q}$$
$$x_2=\frac{a p q}{a q^2+p^2}+\frac{a q}{4 p}+\frac{p}{4 q}$$
$$x_3=\frac{1}{8} \left(\frac{16 a p q \left(a q^2+p^2\right)}{a^2 q^4+6 a p^2
   q^2+p^4}+\frac{4 a p q}{a q^2+p^2}+\frac{a q}{p}+\frac{p}{q}\right)$$

Comment: This appears to be an alternate method for generating rational approximations, rather than bounds on the error of the method described.

Comment: @wnoise. I agree but I need some fun